# Query with Backand REST API

Tags: backand

I have a table for sport. Sample of table is include here. I want to execute "SELECT * FROM sport WHERE TYPE='indoor'" this kind of query using backand REST api.

I have read following article. But i was unable to success. Please explain How do we execute this kind of queries and How do we use filter,exclude, deep,search and pageSize with backand REST API.

[image]

Comment: Why is this tagget with 'ionic famework' ? You should create methods in your API that returns the desired data. You could add filter parameters like this '[URL]/api/sports?filter=indoor' and then make the controller aware of this param.

Comment: are you using back& Queries(/1/query/data/asdf) or calling an object (1/objects/asdf)?

Comment: can you share some example ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use filter parameter in your query.

Your filter is like this:

```
   [ {    "fieldName": "type",   
          "operator": "equal",    
          "value": "Indoor"  }]
```

You can find more information in **Rest** tab in your object.